# Maven:install jar file during build process

Tags: maven, ant, pom.xml, maven-antrun-plugin

I have got a requirement as follows.
I need to run ant build file during maven build process. I need to invoke the build.xml from my pom.xml file. I have done that using maven-antrun-plugin. Now I need to install the ant build generated jar file automatically into my local repository before maven compiles my project source. I tried using build-helper-maven-plugin but it did not help. Either I am doing something wrong, or i am not doing right. Please help.

**Update**

Thank you. ant maven tasks worked for me as well. However I am runing into the following exception at the end of the build process. Any help is highly appreciated.
`org.apache.tools.ant.ExitException: Permission (java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM) was not granted. at org.apache.tools.ant.types.Permissions$MySM.checkExit(Permissions.java:196) at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:99) at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:275) at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:376) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599) at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:217) at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:152) at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:771) at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:221) at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135) at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108) at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.Mvn.execute(Mvn.java:81) at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599) at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106) at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348) at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390) at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411) at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399) at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368) at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41) at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251) at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809) at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217) at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280) at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)`

Answer (score 19):

I have encountered the same exception as posted above when I was invoking Maven from within an Ant script using artifact:mvn task. I managed to get rid of it by adding the fork="true" to the task invocation as follows:

```
<artifact:mvn pom="path/to/my-pom.xml" mavenHome="/path/to/maven-2.0.x" fork="true">
    <arg value="install"/>
</artifact:mvn>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all that your project source needs is access to the contents generated by the ant build, you can use build-helper-maven-plugin to [attach the source](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html).

If the contents of the ant build is needed as a dependency, then you should probably move the ant related code to a separate project and build it.

If more details are provided, perhaps, someone can provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Maven Ant Tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html) which is the cousin of maven-antrun-plugin. It allows to invoke some Maven functionalities from ant, like installing your jar into the repository. It worked well for me with an hybrid build half Maven, half Ant.